# merge and redirect functions of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I found a merged question in Stack Overflow, and it was be redirected to another question. But the redirect link can't go to the aim URL **automatically**. This isn't like general wiki mode system (for example: Quora, Wikipedia).

I have 2 questions：

1.Is the redirection added automatically after the questions be merged?
2.Why the redirect of Stackoverflow is not like other wiki system (go to the aim URL **automatically**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The notification is added upon being merged.
2. Well, unlike Wikipedia, there is still something around in both posts—the one that's being merged into another doesn't get the question text merged—there are all sorts of problems around that, so if you're interested in answers after reading the question, you can go to them by clicking a link—as opposed to wondering where one of the questions went.